# Trying to get name,sku,publisher from products with no category ids

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, query

What I m trying to do is a query with name,sku,publisher(custom attribute) for products with no category ids.

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku  FROM catalog_product_entity AS e 
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE l.category_id IS NULL
```

That code gives me only sku. How can I join another table to get the others that I want?
This is something I tried to do but doesn't work. 
attribute_id=71 is name-Title and attribute_id=137 is Publisher

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku , d.value FROM catalog_product_entity AS e 
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE l.category_id IS NULL 
Inner JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS d ON d.entity_id=e.entity_id WHERE d.attribute_id=71 OR d.attribute_id=137
```

Of course I just need the result. I don't mind if the answer is magento way. I couldn't do it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `php script at magento root dir`.

Using magento product collection model get data quickly:

> ```
> require_once 'app/Mage.php';
> Mage::app("admin");
> $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
>           ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
>           ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
>           ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code');
>
> foreach($collection as $product){
>   //sku ->
>   $product->getSku();
>   //name ->
>   $product->getName();
>   // custom
>   $product->getData('custom_attribute_code');
>   $CategoryIds=$product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);
>   // cateory count
>   count($CategoryIds);
> }
> ```

Comment: _getResource() you don't need this.It is giving an error

Comment: it replace by getResource() and it's working